# the function split in javascript not work

Tags: javascript, jsbin

I have a string in javascript. I want to run some code to process the string. The code runs fine but the function `split` did not work.

My code:

```js
    // Raw string
    var str = ' first.getage()  person.getinfo( tow.fff(one) , data ) car.getcompany ';
    
        // Trim the space off of th start and end of str
        var str = str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
        
        /* This says:
        || Find any literal fragment that is ".get"
        || Then find everything that's a character before ".get"...
        || until there's a space.
        || Now replace that particular space with:
        || a space, / , and another space
        */
        var rgx = /\s\b(?=\w*(?=\.get))/g;
        
        var res = str.replace(rgx, ' \/ ');
         var  splitvalue=res.split(" / ");
           for (var i = 0; i <splitvalue.length ; i++) 
            {
              console.log(i+splitvalue[i]);
            }
```

Code online: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yisiyojuce/edit?html,js,output)

The variable `splitvalue` must be an array containing 3 elements but it only contains 1 element. So what is wrong? Why did the `split` function not work here?

Comment: You can't use `.split` that way - you either have to provide a single character, or a regular expression.  You cannot split on a multi-character string like you are trying to do.

Comment: What is in res?

Comment: I'm confused, it's actually working? looking at your jsbin. the problem is on the alert, have your tried `console.log`?

Comment: Joe, that is false information. Multi character strings work fine.

Comment: no the array have only one element I try to alert the length of array and print the length 1

Answer (score 1):

Your array does contain 3 elements. You only see one on jsbin because they interrupt your loop after the first iteration. On the browser console I see:

```
Exiting potential infinite loop at line 19. To disable loop protection: add "// noprotect" to your code
runner-3.41.10.min.js:1:12578
```

Comment: no the array have only one element I try to alert the length of array and print the length 1 @melpomene

Comment: @Sara I ran your snippet here on SO and the jsbin version with `// noprotect` added. In both cases I got 3 elements. Show your code that demonstrates the problem with `length` 1.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for all people answer my question ... the problem was in the browser  of my IDE ... it did not execute some function ... when I try other browser it work fine